# Disk partitioning, partition shrinking for triple-boot

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I have the following situation on my main SSD:

1. Boot EFI
2. Windows 10 main (C:)
3. Linux SWAP
4. Ubuntu 15.10 main
5. FAT 32 automounted common partition

Now, I would like to add Kali Linux and triple-boot my PC. Partitions are in the order listed above and the disk is completely partitioned with no unallocated space.

I want to shrink Win and Ubuntu main partitions to retrieve two blocks of unallocated space and move these blocks in the end of the disk merging them to an unique bigger space to put Kali on.

Is it possible? Are there any risks to mess up the boot? How should I do to shrink partitions and move unallocated blocks in the end?

I used to manage partitions with GParted but it seems not to recognize my disk while the utilities included both in Windows and in Ubuntu can. Could booting GParted from USB resolve this issue?

Thanx in advance for your help

Comment: I would try gparted from a live usb/cd, as it is the best repartitioning system for your situation in my opinion.

Comment: I tried GParted live USB and it can see my SSD. The problem with the preinstalled GParted on live distros was that is generally an old version of the software and cannot recognize NVMe disks. Installed Kali on the unallocated space just created, everything is ok, except for Ubuntu that takes very long time to boot.

Comment: So all sorted in the end? Ubuntu is a bit slow at the best of times, if any pro linux users can offer an insight as to why I would also be interested.

Comment: Effectively Ubuntu is a bit slow, but its time to boot has significantly increased (up to 10 times) after installing Kali.

Comment: Interesting to note.